React on Azure static web app token does not persist on refresh
I deploy a react application to an Azure static web app.
My authentication works via msal with following config:
export const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "XXXXXXXXX",
        authority: b2cPolicies.authorities.signUpSignIn.authority,
        knownAuthorities: [b2cPolicies.authorityDomain],
        redirectUri: "https://XXXXX.azurestaticapps.net/",
        postLogoutRedirectUri: "https://XXXXXXXXX.azurestaticapps.net/"
        //redirectUri: "/",
        //postLogoutRedirectUri: "/"
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "localStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: true
    },
    system: {
        allowNativeBroker: false,
    }
};
export const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

If I run my app locally (redirectUri etc to "/"), the token is reused correctly when I refresh the page.
If I deploy my app and I refresh the page, my token returns "undefined"
When moving between pages the token keeps working, it's just gone as soon as I refresh.
I tried setting the storage to sessionStorage, but that also doesn't help.

I created simple React app with Azure B2C and deployed to the Azure Static web app.
Check that the redirectUri and postLogoutRedirectUri are correctly configured to match your deployed app's URL.  Make sure the authority and knownAuthorities are correctly set and match the configuration in Azure AD B2C.
Config.js:
export const config = {
    ClientId: '<ClientId>',
    redirectUri: '<AzurestaticwebURL>',
    scopes: ['openid', 'profile'],
    authority: 'https://<your_Tenant>.b2clogin.com/<your_Tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/<Policy_Name>',
    knownAuthorities: ['https://<your_Tenant>.b2clogin.com/kazureb2c.onmicrosoft.com/<Policy_Name>'],
  };

Below is my complete code:
index.js:
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { MsalProvider } from '@azure/msal-react';
import App from './App';
import { config } from './Config';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication({
  auth: {
    clientId: config.clientId,
    redirectUri: config.redirectUri,
    authority: config.authority,
    knownAuthorities: config.knownAuthorities,
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
    storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
  },
});
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
        <App />
      </MsalProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
  );
  reportWebVitals();

App.js:
import React from 'react';
import { useMsal } from '@azure/msal-react';
import AuthButton from './AuthButton';
function App() {
  const { accounts, instance } = useMsal();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>MSAL React App</h1>
        {accounts.length === 0 ? (
          <AuthButton msalInstance={instance} />
        ) : (
          <div>
            <p>Welcome</p>
            <button onClick={() => instance.logout()}>Logout</button>
          </div>
        )}
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;

AuthButton.js:
import React from 'react';
import { config } from './Config';
function AuthButton({ msalInstance }) {
  const login = async () => {
    try {
      await msalInstance.loginPopup({
        scopes: config.scopes,
        prompt: 'login',
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={login}>Login</button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default AuthButton;

I used below staticwebapp config file to deploy the react app to azure static web for redirect URLs.
staticwebapp.config.json:
{
    "routes": [
      {
        "route": "/login",
        "allowedRoles": ["authenticated"]
      },
      {
        "route": "/logout",
        "allowedRoles": ["authenticated"]
      },
      {
        "route": "/",
        "serve": "/index.html",
        "statusCode": 200
      }
    ],
    "responseOverrides": {
      "401": {
        "redirect": "/login",
        "statusCode": 302
      },
      "404": {
        "serve": "/index.html",
        "statusCode": 200
      }
    },
    "globalHeaders": {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization"
    }
  }  

Azure Output:

After refreshing, I got below output without any Errors.

